# Next.js 13 App Folder Get Path in Server Component

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am working on making pages private and only accessible to users with a specific role.
My idea is to save the URL (for example, "/create-post") in my mssql database with a binding to all roles that should have access to this route.

My problem is how to get the path in the server component to validate if the user can access this route?

help appreciated

If you have any other appreciated I would like to hear them

Regards,
Tell T.

Answer (score -2):

You can accomplish this request using cookie control.
I suggest examining the cookie component from the following link;
https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cookies.

This will fulfill your request.